# Vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

я использую vue-multiselect вот пример, только я получаю свои данные названия компаний в моем случае, а не как в данном примере названия стран и проблема заключается в том что не получается выбрать две фирмы с одинаковым названием.На изображении видно что я выбрал Adidas (Germany),а Adidas(France) выбрать не возможно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код template :

```
<label class="typo__label" for="ajax">Async multiselect</label>
  <multiselect v-model="selectedCountries" id="ajax" label="name" track-by="code" placeholder="Type to search" open-direction="bottom" :options="countries" :multiple="true" :searchable="true" :loading="isLoading" :internal-search="false" :clear-on-select="false" :close-on-select="false" :options-limit="300" :limit="3" :limit-text="limitText" :max-height="600" :show-no-results="false" :hide-selected="true" @search-change="asyncFind">
    <template slot="tag" slot-scope="{ option, remove }"><span class="custom__tag"><span>{{ option.name }}</span><span class="custom__remove" @click="remove(option)"></span></span></template>
    <template slot="clear" slot-scope="props">
      <div class="multiselect__clear" v-if="selectedCountries.length" @mousedown.prevent.stop="clearAll(props.search)"></div>
    </template><span slot="noResult">Oops! No elements found. Consider changing the search query.</span>
  </multiselect>
  <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ selectedCountries  }}</code></pre>
```

Comment: может у них id одинаковое?

Comment: нет ID разные ,и когда ставлю вместо label="name" , label="id" то все работает как нужно просто в поиске тогда вводить нужно   ID а не имя компании

Comment: `name` должно быть уникальным, в доках это написано. Предлагаю в `name` писать что-то вроде "Adidas Germany" и "Adidas France" а название компании хранить например в `company`. Ну и в шаблоне тэга выводить `company` вместо `name`

Comment: просто я еще рассматриваю тот момент что могут быть 2-3 Adidas Germany даже с тем же городом но разными адресами.По этому планировал что уникальным будет ID

Answer (score 1):

При работе с объектами необходимо предоставить дополнительные пропсы: label и track-by.

```
track-by="code"
```

track-by используется для идентификации опции в списке опций, поэтому его значение должно быть уникальным.